# Добавление в DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Дано:

`List<Complex> impedance;`

`double[] frequence;`

Требуется добавить в DataGridView, в котором два столба impedance и frequence.

p.s.

Да, можно привязать к bindingSource, в который будем класть объекты класса, который хранит frequence и impedance, но без него можно как-то сделать?

Comment: `ObservableCollection<YouClass> -> xaml -> element -> binding` клас включает в себя оба значения, но не в виде массивов, массивом будет ObservableCollection. `class YouClass { Complex impedance; double frequence; }`

Comment: Обычным присвоением можно обойтись? (цикл)

Comment: 1. Укажите что используете (WPF/WinForms). 2. `(цикл)` - Что мешает проверить? Берем `dataGridView1.Columns.Add`/`dataGridView1.Rows.Add` и вперед...